# SelectionTracker.startRange can only be called from within the same library group (groupId=androidx.recyclerview)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

So I was trying to implement recyclerview list selection with `recyclerview-selection` library, but I got lint error for this code.

```
selectionTracker.startRange(0)
selectionTracker.extendRange(viewAdapter.itemCount)
```

lint error:

```
SelectionTracker.startRange can only be called from within the same library group (groupId=androidx.recyclerview)
```

I was using the latest version of this library

```
implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview-selection:1.1.0-alpha01'
```

I didn't find documents on the Android developer website so I looked into the source code comments. If I understand it correctly I can implement a select-all feature with the above code, am I right? If it's not what's the correct way to implement it?

What does the lint error means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many methods in `SelectionTracker` are marked as

```
@hide
@RestrictTo(LIBRARY_GROUP)
```

including range methods. This means that they are for internal use. At least for now.